# If $aR$ is free, how can I conclude $a$ is not a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M=R_R$. I need to show that every submodule of $M$ is free if and only if $R$ is a PID.

 For the first implication, assume that every submodule of $M$ is free.

 If I take an element $a \in R$, $a$ non-zero, then I know that $aR$ is free, as a submodule of $M$.
How do I show that $a$ is not a zero divisor? Then I could conclude that $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to note that a basis for a free ideal *in a commutative ring* can only have one generator.  (There are actually some exotic cases in noncommutative rings that permit ideals of higher rank!)

For if $b_1, b_2$ were two different basis elements, then $b_1b_2\in b_1R\cap b_2R=\{0\}$. By uniqueness of representation this would imply $b_2=0$, a contradiction because $0$ cannot be a basis element.

So let $x\in aR$ be a basis element.  In particular $x=ar$ for some $r\in R$. But if $ab=0$ for some nonzero $b\in R$, you'd have that $xr=0$. Since $x$ is the basis for $aR$, that would imply $r=0$ and in turn $x=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Now if I want to show that every ideal in $R$ is principal, suppose that $I$ is an ideal in $R$. Can I show that $I$ has a basis consisting of only one element? If I suppose that $I$ has a basis of two elements, say $\{x_1,x_2\}$, how do I get a contradiction?

Comment: @wwinters57 That was literally the first thing we did in this solution.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, thank you.

Comment: What about the other direction? Suppose now $R$ is PID and let $N$ be a submodule of $M=R_R$. How do I show that $N$ is free?

Comment: @wwinters57 Well, doesn't it seem natural to check if $a$ is a basis for $(a)$?